# Printing Paths in Dijkstra's shortest path Python3

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, path, shortest-path, dijkstra

I'm having issues with the code below where it's not displaying any paths for each vertex. Vertex and Distance from the source is displaying correctly, but for the path section of the output is blank. What am I missing? I would love to get some feedbacks or suggestions or even answer to this nightmare. I just can't seem to figure out what is causing the paths from displaying anything. I'm still fairly new to Python and I could really use some help!

[Output of my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y42Fy.png)

```
class Graph:

    def minDistance(self, dist, queue):
        # Initialize min value and min_index as -1
        minimum = float("Inf")
        min_index = -1

        # from the dist array,pick one which
        # has min value and is till in queue
        for i in range(len(dist)):
            if dist[i] < minimum and i in queue:
                minimum = dist[i]
                min_index = i
        return min_index


    def printPath(self, parent, j):

        # Base Case : If j is source
        if parent[j] == -1:
            print()
            j,
            return
        self.printPath(parent, parent[j])
        print()
        j,


    def printSolution(self, dist, parent):
        src = 0
        print("Vertex \t\tDistance from Source\tPath")
        for i in range(1, len(dist)):
            print(("\n%d --> %d \t\t%d \t\t\t\t\t" % (src, i, dist[i])), end=' ')
            self.printPath(parent, i)


    def dijkstra(self, graph, src):
        row = len(graph)
        col = len(graph[0])        
        dist = [float("Inf")] * row        
        parent = [-1] * row        
        dist[src] = 0  
        queue = []
        for i in range(row):
            queue.append(i)        
        while queue:            
            u = self.minDistance(dist, queue)            
            queue.remove(u)            
            for i in range(col):                
                if graph[u][i] and i in queue:
                    if dist[u] + graph[u][i] < dist[i]:
                        dist[i] = dist[u] + graph[u][i]
                        parent[i] = u        
        self.printSolution(dist, parent)


g = Graph()

graph = [[0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
     [4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0],
     [0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2],
     [0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 4, 14, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6],
     [8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7],
     [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0]
     ]


g.dijkstra(graph, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue with your code is that the `printPath` method is only outputting blanks and secondly, the `printSolution` method is not including the results of the `printPath` method.  To fix these problems:
1 rewrite the printPath function as below:

```
def printPath(self, parent, j, l):
    # Returns a list from destination to source
    # Base case when j = source
    if parent[j] == -1:
       return l
    else:
       l.append(j)
       return self.printPath(parent, parent[j], l)
```

Then rewrite the `printSolution` method as follows:
Note: I used the f format structure to simplify my print statement

```
def printSolution(self, dist, parent):
    src = 0
    print("Vertex \t\tDistance from Source\tPath")
    
    for i in range(1, len(dist)):
        st = f"\n{src}  --> {i}\t\t{dist[i]}\t\t\t\t\t{self.printPath(parent,i,[])[::-1]}"
        #print(("\n%d --> %d \t\t%d \t\t\t\t\t" % (src, i, dist[i])), end=' ')
        #self.printPath(parent, i)
        print (st)
```